# Notacion cientifica en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo entendido que si colocamos e o E y seguido de un numero es 10 elevado al valor que asigne, pero no entiendo como funciona en esta declaración acompañado de un float.

```
float f = 134.45E-2f;
Console.WriteLine(f); // output: 1.3445
```

Lo saque de esta fuente: [https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types](http://enlace)

Comment: Que no entiendes? Estás declarando 134.45 por 10 elevado a la -2, lo que efectivamente es 1.3445

Comment: es a la menos 2 :o , gracias @Pikoh ;) no lo había visto de esa forma.

Comment: Tranquilo estas cosas pasan :)